# The condition "if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1)" is not getting executed

Tags: java, android

```
weight_spinner= findViewById(R.id.weight_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_weight = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Weight,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_weight.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weight_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_weight);


        weight_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        weight_et.setHint("Weight(kg)");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        weight_et1.setEnabled(false);
                        weight_et.setEnabled(true);

                        if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                        {

                            Thread t = new Thread(){
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    while (!isInterrupted()){
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    count++;
                                                    String Height = height_et.getText().toString().trim();
                                                    String Weight = weight_et.getText().toString().trim();

                                                    String age = age_et.getText().toString().trim();
                                                    String gender =  gender_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                                                    if(Height.isEmpty()){
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    if(Weight.isEmpty()){
                                                        result_tv.setText("");
                                                        return;
                                                    }


                                                    if (gender.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty()){
                                                        fat_tv.setText("");
                                                        age_et.setError("Please Enter Age");
                                                        age_et.requestFocus();
                                                        return;
                                                    }



//Get the user values from the widget reference
                                                    int Age = Integer.parseInt(age);
                                                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(Weight);
                                                    float height = Float.parseFloat(Height)/100;

//Calculate BMI value
                                                    float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
                                                    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                                                    final String rounded_bmivalue= decimalFormat.format(bmiValue);
//Calculate Ideal Weight

                                                    float fatpercent = 0.0f;
                                                    String rounded_fatpercent = null;
                                                    if (gender.equals("Male") && Age <18){
                                                        fatpercent = Childfatpercentage(bmiValue,Age,1);
                                                        rounded_fatpercent = decimalFormat.format(fatpercent);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (gender.equals("Male") && Age >=18){
                                                        fatpercent = Adultfatpercentage(bmiValue,Age,1);
                                                        rounded_fatpercent = decimalFormat.format(fatpercent);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (gender.equals("Female") && Age <18){
                                                       fatpercent = Childfatpercentage(bmiValue,Age,0);
                                                        rounded_fatpercent = decimalFormat.format(fatpercent);
                                                    }
                                                    else if (gender.equals("Female") && Age >=18){
                                                       fatpercent = Adultfatpercentage(bmiValue,Age,0);
                                                        rounded_fatpercent = decimalFormat.format(fatpercent);
                                                    }


//Define the meaning of the bmi value
                                                    final String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                                                    if (bmiValue<16) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4500"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                        fat_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    result_tv.setText(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation);
                                                    fat_tv.setText("Fat : "+rounded_fatpercent+" %");
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            t.start();

                        }

                        if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1){


                            Thread t = new Thread(){
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    while (!isInterrupted()){
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    count++;
                                                    String Height = height_et.getText().toString().trim();
                                                    String Weight = weight_et.getText().toString().trim();
                                                    String Height1 = height_et1.getText().toString().trim();

                                                    if(Height.isEmpty()){
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    if(Weight.isEmpty()){
                                                        result_tv.setText("");
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    if (Height1.isEmpty()){
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(Weight);
                                                    float feet = Float.parseFloat(Height);
                                                    float inches = Float.parseFloat(Height1);
                                                    float height = convertftandin(feet,inches)/100;

//Calculate BMI value
                                                    float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight,height);
                                                    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                                                    String rounded_bmivalue= decimalFormat.format(bmiValue);
//Calculate Ideal Weight
                                                    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                                                    if (bmiValue<16) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4500"));
                                                    }
                                                    else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                                                    }

                                                    result_tv.setText(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation);

                                                }
                                            });
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                            t.start();


                        }

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        weight_et.setHint("Weight(lb)");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);break;
                    case 2:
                        weight_et.setHint("st");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        weight_et1.setHint("lb");break;

                }

            }

        });






}
```

**The condition "if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1)" inside case 0 of onItemSelected is not getting executed only the condition "if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)" is bieng executed.**
**The condition "if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1)" inside case 0 of onItemSelected is not getting executed only the condition "if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)" is bieng executed.**

*Please suggest an edit and solve my problem*

Comment: Please don’t dump all your code. Create a [mcve] and show your attempts at working it out.

Comment: `else if(height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1)` . debug code at first

Comment: @achAmháin code shortened no please look into it

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya your the code didnt worked

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you are in position 0 (aka case 0) :

```
 @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    weight_et.setHint("Weight(kg)");
                    weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    weight_et1.setEnabled(false);
                    weight_et.setEnabled(true);

                    if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0) {...}
```

the code: `height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` is equal to 0 (in position 1 it will equal to 1 and so on)

so the condition: `height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1` will never be called in case 0

Comment: if you want to execute the code in the condition: **height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1**
you need to put it **in case 1**
if you want to execute the code in the condition: **height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2**
you need to put it **in case 2** and so on...

Comment: but i have kg as position 0 and the combination of cm+kg in bmi works but how will the combination of ft+in,kg work as the position of kg remains 0

Comment: So maybe you need to re-think your logic